# Unable to debug Sitecore 10.2 docker containers-msvsmon process is not getting enabled

Tags: docker, container

[image]

The msvsmon process is not enabled, so I cannot debug the docker container. Does anybody have any idea how to enable this process?

Comment: In my network I had an issue with the proper packages downloading for debugging. I ended up mapping a volume to the debugging app with my host machine.

Comment: We had an issue like this on a client network, we had to set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 to workaround it.